# For Servicemix, Is there a command I can execute which tells me the status of the server?

Tags: shell, apache-servicemix

I'm looking for a unix script or command I can execute which will tell me if ServiceMix is running, similar to bin/activemq status. Is there any way of doing this out-of-the-box with ServiceMix?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using servicemix version 4.5.2

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the version you use, there is either a *status* shell script available 
It'll tell you if it's *Running* or *Not Running ...*

Comment: I'm using version 4.5.2, which doesn't have a script named status

Answer (score 0):

procedure to create servicemix service

```
karaf@root> features:install wrapper
 wrapper:install -s AUTO_START -n KARAF -d Karaf -D "Karaf Service"
```

On Redhat/Fedora/CentOS Systems:
  To install the service:

```
$ ln -s /home/onofreje/apache-karaf-2.1.3/bin/KARAF-service /etc/init.d/
$ chkconfig KARAF-service --add
```

To start the service when the machine is rebooted:

```
$ chkconfig KARAF-service on
```

To disable starting the service when the machine is rebooted:
    $ chkconfig KARAF-service off

To start the service:

```
 $ service KARAF-service start
```

To stop the service:

```
 $ service KARAF-service stop
```

To uninstall the service :

```
 $ chkconfig KARAF-service --del
    $ rm /etc/init.d/KARAF-service
```

On Ubuntu/Debian Systems:
  To install the service:

```
 $ ln -s /home/onofreje/apache-karaf-2.1.3/bin/KARAF-service /etc/init.d/
```

To start the service when the machine is rebooted:

```
 $ update-rc.d KARAF-service defaults
```

To disable starting the service when the machine is rebooted:

```
$ update-rc.d -f KARAF-service remove
```

To start the service:

```
$ /etc/init.d/KARAF-service start
```

To stop the service:

```
 $ /etc/init.d/KARAF-service stop
```

To uninstall the service :

```
$ rm /etc/init.d/KARAF-service
```

To check the status in CentOS `service KARAF-service status` it will tell you the status of the service.